# sudo for rdist on AIX 6.1

Tags: sudo, aix, synchronization

I have a master-slave pair of AIX servers.

Currently, the rdist via root user from master server is used to sync files between the two servers. I am struggling to replace root user with other remote user and use sudo to obtain elevated access. I have been successful in logging in as a remote user into slave server when invoking rdist from a master server. However, I am struggling to setup sudo on inbound rdist connection on slave server. I need to run rdist as remote user on master, rdist connects to slave server as the remote user, grant sudo access for a remote user on slave server to run as root (after remotely connecting to slave).

I have tried adding sudo for rdist and rdistd but had no luck. I do not know what program/process runs on slave when rdist is invoked so not sure what additional sudos' are required.

Comment: You may want to check the rdist part of https://rabbitbytes.wordpress.com/2013/04/20/non-root-remote-updating/

Comment: Clever — they wrapped the rdist command for the remote user to be a call to `sudo rdist`!

Comment: Looks like a 'tailored' way.  Will give it a try.